# A boolean function for finding if a HSL based color is near to another color

Tags: c#, colors

I wanted to write a function which could check if color is close to a background color.

For this i make use of the HSL color scheme, let me explain that a bit; HSL colors are defined as Hue Saturation and lightness. In short Hue tells you which color of the rainbow is used and its in the range 0 to 360. And its on the Hue that i would like check.

So Saturation how strong the color is, like pure or mixed with grey 
or Lightness which speaks for itself are not compared. I only want to check for Hue. 
At first i wrote a Near function like this:

```
Private boolean Near(int background, int mycolor, int difference)
{
  if(math.abs( background - mycolor)<difference){return true;}else{return false}
}
```

Later i realized this is wrong. Because HSL is like the image below you see in there the colors are as a circle, so starting at red 0 and it is red again at 360. 
So a Hue value of 358 and 4 are close together, the above function wouldn't reflect that.

(Saturation goes to the center 0..100 
 lightens 0..100 is like going up or down
 and Hue is from 0 to 360 degrees around. )

[image]

I could rewrite a function with a large if then construction, so that for example if the background where red 5 and the allowed difference is 20 then `mycolor` would be in range if it is < 5+20 or > (360-(5-20)) .. so making a special construction if the Hue difference would be crossing the 0 or 360 limits.

Well that would work, but then i wondered might it be possible to replace such "if then" construction with a modulo calculation in a single line ?, it keeps me wondering still
As modulo computations can be used to check within a border and if its over the border of 360 it would be red again close to zero,

well i think so, such line might also contain some AND or OR and subtractions or ABS functions..might it be possible to write it in one comparison line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is ensure that the values you are comparing are as close as they can be.  For instance, if `background = 358`, and `mycolor = 4`, then they could be made closer by subtracting `360` from `background`, which doesn't change the effective value.  They need to be made closer as long as the difference > `180`.

```
if (mycolor - background > 180) mycolor -= 360;
if (background - mycolor > 180) background -= 360;
```

With these transformations, your original logic should then be correct (the `if` is unnecessary):

```
return Math.Abs(background - mycolor) < difference;
```

---

**Edit**: I have found a simpler expression that seems to be correct.

```
return Math.Abs(background - mycolor) % (361 - difference) < difference;
```

Comment: the first one you wrote, i had something in mind like that one too we had the same ideas there, the final one seams it, i'm curious dough why its 361 and not 360 in there ?

Comment: @user613326: To be honest, I discovered the `361` by trial-and-error.  I figured some form using modulus would work, and wrote a script to compare the results between the original and the new code for all possible inputs.  It was incorrect with `360`, but correct with `361`.  I didn't dig into it any further to determine why.

Comment: If both 0 and 360 are valid values, that would mean that there are 361 possible values - which is why the mod is 361 and not 360.  360 would work if there were only 360 possible values (IE 0 to 359 inclusive)

Comment: @thorkia: It is actually 0 to 359 inclusive.  The value 360 is identical to the value 0 in terms of what color it represents.

Comment: @mellamokb - 360 may be the same color, but it is a valid value.  You can set the color value to 360, and it then ask the for value back and it will say 360 not 0.